# What is wrong with my javascript/jquery code here?

Tags: ajax, jquery

---

HTML

---

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="txt"/>
<input type="button" onclick="get()"/>
</form>
```

returns

---

### Javascript

---

returns

```
function get(){
var ik=$('#txt').value();
$.get('action.php',{text:ik});
}
```

---

### PHP

---

```
<?php $text=$_GET['txt']; print $text?>
```

> When I look at firebug I get a notice saying that index txt is
>      undefined, I tried everything but it's not working. What am I doing
>      wrong?

Answer (score 2):

$('#txt') will search for an element with id=txt and you don't have any element with id "txt" on your HTML code.

To get a value of the field you should use the .val() method.

The code that should work for you is:

```
$('input[name="txt"]').val();
```

Or define an id to your field and your code should be like this:

```
$('#txt').val();
```

In your PHP code your are looking for a variable called "txt" and in your Javascript code you are defining "text" as your variable so... you should read the **$_GET['text']**;

[]'s
Igor.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `{text:ik}`, so in your `action.php` you should get the value you want from `$_GET['text']` not `$_GET['txt']`

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `#txt` element?

Try

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt"/>
<input type="button" onclick="get()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so there are **three** problems going on.

First, you probably want `id=txt` in the HTML. You currently have `name=txt`. The `#txt` is going to retrieve the ID attribute in the HTML (not the Name attribute).

Here, use this for the HTML:

```
<form method="GET"> 

  <!-- You need to have an ID value, if you are using #txt in jQuery -->
  <!-- I assign both ID and Name to the same value -->
  <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt"/>

  <input type="button" onclick="get()"/> 
</form>
```

Second, your call to action.php is passing the key "text", not "txt", and third you need to use val().

This might work for the JavaScript:

```
function get(){  

  // The #txt is getting an ID value
  // You also need to use val() instead of value()  ... according to @Igor
  var ik=$('#txt').val(); 

  // If PHP is looking for a txt key, you'll want that here as well
  // The key could by "mykey" as long as PHP expects "mykey".
  $.get('action.php',{txt:ik});

}
```

So, you'll want to correct both those errors.

The PHP looks fine.

Comment: nope I just forgot to include the id in this code but it is in the original one.

Comment: Thank all of you guys for your answers. The problem was with the "text"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `val()` method instead off `value()`;

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="go"/>
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){
  var ik=$(input'[name=txt]').val();
  $.get('action.php',{txt : ik},function(data){
      //do whatever with the response from get call
  });
});
```